# How can I add headers to Storage::disk('public')

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to gzip a large json file I've stored in Storage::disk('public').

A few things I've tried.

This bit of code seems to have no effect at all. When routing to the file path, it is encoded. The "Content-Encoding" header is not in the response headers.

```
$content = gzencode(json_encode($array), 9);

Storage::disk("public")->put(
   $path,
   $content,
   [
       "Content-Encoding" => "gzip",
       "Content-Length" => strlen($content),
   ]
);
```

I had a feeling this code below wouldn't work, but tried it anyway. As expected, it just has the response headers at the top of the page response and the json file is encoded below it. Assumedly because the put function just stringifies the response and does not affect the headers.

```
$content = gzencode(json_encode($array), 9);

Storage::disk("public")->put(
    $path,
    response($content)->withHeaders([
        "Content-Encoding" => "gzip",
        "Content-Length" => strlen($content),
    ])
);
```

If possible, I'd like to avoid having to create a route and returning a response that way.

If no other option is available, I have seen some people mention [using the s3 storage facade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989605/add-metadata-headers-expires-cachecontrol-to-a-file-uploaded-to-amazon-s3-us), but once again, I'd prefer to keep it in the 'public' storage.

Comment: Not clear if the file is already compressed or if you want to compress it on the fly (on each request).

Comment: It is already encoded. I'll add that into the original question.

Comment: You're encoding & compressing on the fly (`$content = gzencode(json_encode($array), 9);`) but at the same time, you claim to have it already encoded & compressed (`... $path, ...`). Which is which?

Comment: Content encoding headers are only applicable as part of a request/response. They have no effect to data which is at rest on a drive somewhere. If you want to return your response gzipped I suggest you do that via webserver configuration. In which case you should not gzip your json at all and let the webserver handle that when generating the response. I think it's a lot more complex to do it differently